# Allow form autofill inside of Chrome Extension Popup Window

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension, autocomplete

I've built a Chrome Extension which passes data from a form using json to an external source. However, I would like to allow users to save their username and password which are required to submit the data. I have attempted adding x-autocompletetype attributes to my inputs to no avail.

How can I allow users to save this information, or make Chrome autofill these inputs?

```
<div class="col-6">
  User: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" class="form-control" required x-autocompletetype="username">
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  Pass: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="form-control" required x-autocompletetype="password">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience of testing, the x-autocomplete tag does nothing in the latest chrome version. Instead try to use autocomplete tags on your input tags, and set their values according to the HTML spec here http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#autofill-field .

For example:

```
<input name="username" autocomplete="username" type="text" placeholder="username" required>
```

Also keep in mind that the parent form tag needs autocomplete="on" and method="POST".
Hope it works.

Comment: Appreciate the input, no luck yet!