# How to enable autofill for a form inside a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, autocomplete, autofill

I'm developing a Chrome extension which requires a basic authentication in order to retrieve some user data.

So inside my extension's popup I have a form:

```
<form id="login-form" class="ui form" action="#" method="post">
    <div class="two fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label for="username">Nom d'utilisateur</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="username" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur / e-mail..." required>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Mot de passe..." required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui centered grid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="six wide column">
                <button class="ui fluid teal button" type="submit">Se connecter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This form is managed by Javascript and sent with AJAX.

Unfortunately, Google Chrome never suggests me anything for the `username` field like it does normally with a "history" dropdown list.
It does not ask me either if I want to save the login/password in Chrome's manager.

Is there a restriction for forms in popups?

Comment: Technically, it's a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432451/allow-form-autofill-inside-of-chrome-extension-popup-window and I suppose no solution exists.

Comment: What about a workaround: display the form in a popup window created with `chrome.windows.create({type: "popup", .......}, ....)`? Some sites do it (mozilla's for one).